# a4j not working after session timeout in jsf and managed bean viewscoped

Tags: jsf

I have developed an application which have `ViewScoped` and `SessionScoped` for the managed beans. All the module which required user to login, the managed beans will be in `SessionScoped` and non-login page will be in `ViewScoped`. Currently, the problem is that when the session is time out which is by default after 30 minutes, the non-login page behaved weirdly where the commandButton is not sending the request to server and it also happen to all the button with ajax behaviour for the page.

I also want to know why the page is behaving like that as there is no session. Is it because of the `ViewScoped` which create a temp session to hold the page as long as the user didn't navigate to other pages?

I have tried most of the suggestion given out there.

Comment: When you said "a4j" do you mean RichFaces' `<a4j:xxx>` components?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [BalusC's Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

> •@ViewScoped: a bean in this scope lives as long as you're interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It get created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed once you postback to a different view. It doesn't immediately get destroyed when you leave/close the view by a GET Request, but it is not accessible the usual way anymore. JSF stores the bean in the UIViewRoot#getViewMap() with the managed bean name as key, which is in turn stored in the session. You need to return null or void from action (listener) methods to keep the bean alive. Use this scope for more complex forms which use ajax, data tables and/or several rendered/disabled attributes whose state needs to be retained in the subsequent requests within the same browser window/tab (view).
>
> •@SessionScoped: a bean in this scope lives as long as the HTTP session lives. It get created upon the first HTTP request involving this bean in the session and get destroyed when the HTTP session is invalidated (or when you manually remove the bean from the session map). JSF stores the bean as an attribute of HttpSession with the managed bean name as key. It is also available by ExternalContext#getSessionMap(). Use this scope for pure session-scoped data which can safely be shared among all browser windows/tabs (views) within the same session. For example, the logged-in user, the user preferences such as user-specific settings and the chosen language/locale, etc.

`ViewScoped` beans are stored in the UIViewRoot which in turn is stored in the users session, thus the `ViewScoped` beans are indirectly also stored in session.  After the session expires and is destroyed, the `ViewScoped` beans get destroyed as well and if you are referencing something in your code of that LoginBean that is expecting state, or perhaps you are using a third party component that requires state (Eg. a4j), then that can explain the wierdness.

I suggest switching to `RequestScoped` for your LoginBean.  I have never run into a situation where I needed `ViewScoped` backing beans for logging into an application.

Comment: >> the ViewScoped is not for the LoginBean. There is a page that is not required for user to login. It is like a search page where a lot of ajax behaviour inside. That's why I used ViewScoped for that. As per your explaination, 'ViewScoped beans are indirectly also stored in session. After the session expires and is destroyed, the ViewScoped beans get destroyed as well'. Currently, what i did is manipulating the session count in JavaScript which I think is not the best solution to force the user to reload the page back after 30 minutes.